How to check in C# if Python is installed?
I would like to check whether Python exists or not when I start my form.
I need a method or a way to determine whether it is installed or not so i can use it in the usecase described above.

private bool IsPythonInstalled()
{
    try
    {
        using var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "--version";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();
        
        var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();

        return output.Contains("python", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

This method attempts to execute the command python --version to determine the Python Version.  If Python is not installed or an error occurs, such as an exception or unexpected output, the method will return false.

I have another question, I have a folder with all the python script, and I would like it to execute the script in the folder where my application is installed no matter where the folder is located.

@alextoutcourt72 Feel free to ask another question.

In this case you can use relative paths (for example ./ means in this Directory.
You can use it like this:
./script.py as Path. if you use ../ you go one Directory above.
The best would be if you read something about relative directory paths, it comes in handy a lot of times

^^ be aware that when using relative paths, "relative to what" matters. It may not always be relative to the directory the .exe is located in.
